# Google App Engine. TextProperty reset to ""

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I run a small video game. Each player has an account model with a variety of properties.

I recently added a TextProperty to track player badges. These are just an ASCII character that is appended to the account.badges property as they are awarded.

Because the properly is new, most account models don't have this property. In about 3 places throughout the site I have some code that looks like this

```
if not player.badges:
  player.badges = ""

player.badges += "A"
player.put_memcache()
player.put()
```

For some reason, one of the players badges keeps getting reset to "" (empty string). I can't for the life of me work out how or why.

I've not worked with TextProperties before. Is there some strange behaviour I don't understand?

Do TextProperties not play nice with the memcache?

The account is not getting reset to some old state because other properties seem to be storing values correctly. Its just this one TextProperty.

Anyhow, I'm confused and would appreciated some fresh ideas that would help me track down the issue.

**Question Answers**

The badges propery is just defined like this

```
class Account(db.Model):
    
    badges = db.TextProperty()
    
    email = db.StringProperty()
    alias = db.StringProperty()
    avatar = db.IntegerProperty()
```

put_memchche is just a wrapper around memcache set.

```
def put_memchche(self):
    memcache.set("account" + self.key().name(), self)
```

Comment: how do you define the badges property? and what does put_memcache do??? Also I think you don't need the if part, if you define the default to be ""

Comment: Not sure what's going on (afaict, you are doing it right), but maybe you can help yourself figure it out by adding logging. import logging; logging.debug('this will appear in your logs').

Comment: thanks Marcadian, I will add a default and remove the ifs. Thanks allyourcode. I do do a lot of logging around the place, I might add some special logs just around this one players account.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, text is similar to string, the difference is just text can contain more character and cannot be indexed. If you specify the default to "" I think you do not need the if part. Is it only happen for one player? Are you sure on runtime it hits the player.badges += 'A'. It would be easier to debug if you provide more code, based on your example, I don't see a problem why badges do not changed.